# New-AzWebApp select Stack settings to .NET Core

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-web-app-service, azure-powershell

How can I execute Azure Powershell command New-AzWebApp to have .NET Core as Stack selected? I can not see any parameter and documentation that could help.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.websites/New-AzWebApp?view=azps-2.6.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could not set it with only this command, the `New-AzWebApp` does not support to do that. You need to use `New-AzWebApp` to create the web app and use `New-AzResource` to set the `CURRENT_STACK` with `dotnetcore`.

Try the command as below, it works fine on my side.

```
New-AzWebApp -ResourceGroupName <ResourceGroupName> -Name <web-app-name> -AppServicePlan <app-service-plan-name>
$PropertiesObject = @{
    "CURRENT_STACK" =  "dotnetcore"
}
New-AzResource -PropertyObject $PropertiesObject -ResourceGroupName <ResourceGroupName> -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites/config -ResourceName "<web-app-name>/metadata" -ApiVersion 2018-02-01 -Force
```

[image]

**Note**: If you have set other properties in the `metadata`, like Deployment Center source, you also need to include them in the  `$PropertiesObject`, becasue the command will overwrite `$PropertiesObject`.

**Besides**, to check the properties of the metadata of your web app, you could use the command as below.

```
$resource = Invoke-AzResourceAction -ResourceGroupName <ResourceGroupName> -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites/config -ResourceName "<web-app-name>/metadata" -Action list -ApiVersion 2018-02-01 -Force
$resource.Properties
```